# How to achieve full text search in solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr for search in products table, what i want if someone searches about a product then only that product will be appear on ui. Like if i search

> `SAMSUNG 840 EVO 1 TB Desktop Internal Hard Drive (MZ-7TE1T0BW)`

then only this product will appear but what happens it shows all the product related to samsung. I am using this type of field

```
<field name="pro_name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of the field `"pro_name"` to `String` and re-index the data.

Comment: did you check the indexed string in the analysis tool?

Comment: yes i did it shows the result but i want only single row that contains exact pro_name

Comment: In order to achieve the exact search, you need to change the field type from text to string and re-start the server. Once server is restarted , please re-index the data.